# My bluetooth keyboard's skip/back buttons don't fast forward/rewind

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, music-player, external-keyboard

I recently purchased [Satechi's Bluetooth Multimedia Remote Control](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/bluetooth/bluetooth-remote/satechi-bluetooth-remote-control) so I could control my music without looking (i.e. without removing my hands from my pockets and exposing them to winter). Essentially, this pairs as a bluetooth keyboard with media keys, which is why I said "bluetooth keyboard" in title, because I imagine it is functionally the same.

Here's my problem: pressing and holding the skip button does not fast forward as expected (likewise for the back button and rewinding). I noticed that the default music app immediately skips when the button is pressed, while the doubleTwist app waits until the button is released to skip; this makes me think that each app decides how to handle the input from the media keys. Any suggestions for a workaround or an app that will respond appropriately to my input?

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII (SAMSUNG-SGH-1747) running ICS (Android version 4.0.4). It is not rooted.